# Getting ID (PK) from Table based on Selected Columns in ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a table of *STATUS* and it contains these columns:

`ID ColA ColB ColC`

and I want these 3 columns to be shown in ComboBox of a WPF Form. Fine! I will do it by getting Distinct *ColA,ColB,ColC* respectively (*Kindly correct me if I am wrong*)

Now I want to insert an entry in another table based on these comboboxes.

This table, *STATUS_HISTORY* has following structure (not related to question I think):

`ID EmpID (FK from Emp) StatusID (FK from Status) UpdationDate`

Now how would I get the ID of status based on the selected ComboBoxes? Should I use a query like this:

```
SELECT ID from STATUS WHERE ColA LIKE '@SelectedColAValue' AND ColB LIKE '@SelectedColBValue' AND ColC LIKE '@SelectedColCValue'
```

It sounds a very trivial way to me. Is there any better way to do it?

**UPDATE**

*STATUS* Table has rows like this:

```
ID ColA ColB ColC  
1   A1    B1   C1  
2   A1    B1   C2  
3   A1    B2   C1  
4   A1    B2   C2  
5   A1    B3   C1  
6   A1    B3   C2  
7   A2    B1   C1  
8   A2    B1   C2
```

Now if I select A1 in ComboBox1, it corresponds to multiple rows (and so on..)
I hope it explains it further

Comment: Why do you want to display the same `table` row in three different combo-boxes? Are these values independent of each other?

Comment: No they are not independent. They are just like truth table or permutations of these three columns

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do is create `Status` .NET object and bind it to the comboboxes. 
You could bind the same object to all the comboboxes and display which-ever value you want to display in the combo-box.

Check [DisplayMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) , [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) ,[SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SelectedValuePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx)

And Just pass the `SelectedItem` ID to the database.

Comment: Fine! We done it. But by doing so, we will get redundant values for same column

Answer (score 0):

Make the ID column of STATUS a String and generate it like ColA + ColB + ColC. It must be unique for all rows. So then user select values from ComboBoxes make the same concatination of ComboBoxA.Value + ComboBoxB.Value + ComboBoxC.Value. That will be PK to insert in STATUS_HISTORY.

Comment: Why not? Or STATUS table can be edited by the user? If so, tell me the goal of such design, please.